# Is Niqab and Burqa obligatory for women?

Tags: women, hijab, clothing, men-women, obligation

There are some shuyookh who say that niqab and burqa are obligatory because women are altogether 'awrah and they refer to the verse

> “And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts) and not to show off their adornment except only that which is apparent (like both eyes for necessity to see the way, or outer palms of hands or one eye or dress like veil, gloves, headcover, apron), and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms) and not to reveal their adornment except to their husbands, or their fathers, or their husband’s fathers, or their sons, or their husband’s sons, or their brothers or their brother’s sons, or their sister’s sons, or their (Muslim) women (i.e. their sisters in Islam), or the (female) slaves whom their right hands possess, or old male servants who lack vigour, or small children who have no sense of feminine sex. And let them not stamp their feet so as to reveal what they hide of their adornment. And all of you beg Allaah to forgive you all, O believers, that you may be successful”

And they take from this verse as evidence that only the eyes can be seen by men who are non-mahrams, **Question**: is niqab and burkha obligatory for the muslim women, and if so why do the majority of muslim women not use it?

Answer (score 0):

You quoted verse 24:31, let's see the previous verse first, Verse 24:30

> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard
>   their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is
>   Acquainted with what they do.

Clearly said: men should also control their vision.

Now let's come to the point of **Niqab/Burka**, verse you quotes says,

> And tell the believing women to lower their gaze....

It is not dictating **Niqab/Burka** but whatever they wear need to lower that on their face, that's why in many countries women wear **hijab**

For hadiths see [Awrah](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=awrah)

Comment: Please answer the question and try to refute THE VERSE I used, i'm confused at the moment

Answer (score -1):

What is awarah? it means, self centered, or in denial of truth by intention. Every woman is not awarah, but may be some, They were  commanded to wear  a hijab  to be with in the limit of the truth, not to disturb  limit of the men by intention. A woman without hijab with intention is, guilty of arousing man s thoughts in negativity on purpose, and she is guilty of the consequences of her wrong doing, because prostitution is an act based on the intention of a person, and every crime is a result of persons awarah intentions. being awarah, self centered is , in denial of truth and  a crime, and criminals and their crime  have no place in Islam.

Comment: Brother please answer with reference and clear proof and evidence